# How to make JVM start faster?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to speed up Java VM (JVM) startup time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491325/how-to-speed-up-java-vm-jvm-startup-time)

I am writing a command line utility in Java (or probably in another JVM-based language). The problem is JVM start-up time. JVM starts slower than Python and Ruby, for instance.

How to make JVM stat faster? Can I load JVM "in advance" (in Linux and Windows) somehow so that it should not be loaded every time I run my utility in command line?

Comment: I am curious to know how to do this too! I would say slim down your dependent jar files but I hope someone can help with more knowledge.

Comment: On my machine a "HelloWorld" program takes 40 ms to load/run/finish. How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, After running the same version of Java before.

Comment: If you have a complex application, you could make it a service, however a command line utility to use the service is likely to take 60 ms at least.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows there's the Java Quick Starter which comes with the default installation of the JRE.

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/quickstarter.xml

Answer (score 5):

[Nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/) is probably the best solution - it keeps a running JVM instance can then be called by your commands (using a super-lightweight C client).

As an alternative or additional option, you might want to try upgrading to [Java 7](http://jdk7.java.net/) if you haven't done so already - there have been quite a lot of startup time enhancements.

Comment: We use Jruby at work and the jvm startup time and loading of spring objects is the lagging part. We switched to the client server NailGun setup recently and we have a 2X plus improvement speed wise.  We love it!

Answer (score 3):

To *load JVM in advance* you can use [Drip](https://github.com/flatland/drip). It keeps a fresh JVM spun up in reserve with the correct classpath and other JVM options so you can quickly connect and use it when needed, then throw it away. Drip hashes the JVM options and stores information about how to connect to the JVM in a directory with the hash value as its name.

Comment: Thanks man....  I have this base requirement and then I want either a pool of jvms / a new one as soon as I have connected with the one or the last one (I have to profile and judge the strategy) AND then I need round robin way / some other way of selecting the jvm too if I go multiple jvm routes. Has something like that already built on / extending "drip". How am I going to close the jvm? any further resource? wiki is sparse.

Comment: I got them I think from the sh script.