# Small and Lightweight JVM for Scala

Tags: scala, jvm

I need to write a command tool and I would like to write it in Scala. The problem is the start-up time of JVM (Oracle JDK). I did not measure it but I am sure the JVM starts slower than Python, for example.

I have already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796055/how-to-make-jvm-start-faster) a similar question and got answers about tools like [Drip](https://github.com/flatland/drip) and [Nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/). However I would like to use *just* a JVM without any other tools.

Now I am looking for a small and lightweight JVM, which starts as fast as Python and can run Scala generated bytecode. Can I use an `Android JVM` for that purpose ?

Comment: runs as fast as python? you mean 50-500 times slower than C? Java/C# only run about half as fast as C; if speed is what you need, python is NOT where you should look

Comment: The question is about start-up time. And Python is quite good at this. JVM however takes a couple of annoying seconds to get itself running.

Comment: Maybe you could run your program in the background and then just create GUI on user request?

Comment: @ViliusNormantas I need to write a command line tool without any GUI

Answer (score 2):

I have not used any of these, but I think you can run Scala on [Avian](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/), and also it should be possible to compile to native code using [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/). I have just installed [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) which is compiled using gcj, and it's startup time is zero. You might want to use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to shrink the size of your executable as well.

Comment: Thanks, Avian looks interesting. I hope it can run Scala generated code.

Comment: @Michael, yes, it can. See mentions in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/avian

Comment: The link to Avian has died.  Here is one that works: https://github.com/dicej/scala-avian

Answer (score 1):

Would Drip (https://github.com/ninjudd/drip) be of value here perhaps?